# React Connection

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm taking an online free course about React and I'm having problems right after the beginning. It's not connecting, nothing is rendering but I'm copying everything word by word. I would be very thankful if you could tell me what is wrong.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="index.js" type="text/babel"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello, everyone!</h1>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Any errors in your browser's dev-tools console?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an optimal way to work and learn react, you should use packages such as `create-react-app` or `next-js` for that matter, but if you want to get it this way, here is what you need to do:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"
    ></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.17.0/babel.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel" data-presets="es2015,react">
      ReactDOM.render(
        <h1>Hello, everyone!</h1>,
        document.getElementById("root")
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```